# Como alterar as categorias dos produtos no Magento via MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, magento, importação

Eu fiz a importação do [csv](/questions/tagged/csv)dos produtos da minha loja mas eles vieram com as categorias todas trocadas.

Existe alguma maneira de trocar as categorias via [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) ou de alguma outra forma mais rápida?

Comment: Não é mais fácil corrigir a geração do arquivo csv e refazer a importação?

Comment: Esse é o problema, são sei que mudar para associar corretamente as categorias

Comment: O MySql tem o comando SQL UPDATE

Comment: @Tony sei disso .--.

Comment: @luckakashi já começando por aí, você precisar saber onde está o problema para saber o que trocar. Do mais, se você souber, basta construir a lógica em sql ou como o amigo Osvaldo disse, você pode optar pela correção do csv.
Já adianto que não vai existir uma opção mágica que corrige as exportações, se você não informar onde está o problema e qual é a solução.

Comment: @luckakashi: então seu problema não tem a ver com o MySQL e sim com a organização dos dados em sua origem, anterior à carga no SGBD. Você precisa reanalisar estes dados  de forma a gerar o arquivo csv corretamente.

Comment: Para uma melhor resposta, talvez tendo acesso ao CSV ou o SQL dump do mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Como usar o phpMyAdmin para mover produtos de uma categoria para outra em Magento**

O painel de administração oferece um par de formas de mover produtos de uma categoria para outra. Por exemplo, você pode mover um único produto, editando esse produto. Quando você vai a `Catálogo > Gerenciar os produtos` e abre a tela de edição de um produto há uma botão à esquerda que você pode usar para selecionar qual categoria (categorias) o produto deve ser associado. Outra maneira é a de editar a categoria. Quando você vai a `Catálogo > Gerenciar Categorias` e abrir a tela de edição de uma categoria, você pode usar a guia `categoria de Produtos` para remover produtos da categoria ou associar produtos com a categoria.

Ao modificar o banco de dados em que a seu Magento é instalado, você pode mover rapidamente produtos de uma categoria para outra. Por exemplo, esta é uma solução rápida, se você deseja mover todos os produtos de uma categoria para outra. Você pode fazer isso com o phpMyAdmin.

você pode fazer isso com uma consulta SQL que se parece com isso:

```
UPDATE `magento_catalog_category_product` SET `category_id` = 8 WHERE `category_id` = 7
```

Na consulta que você executar você precisa substituir magento com o prefixo real de suas tabelas de banco de dados(se possuir prefixo). Você também tem que substituir os IDs categoria com os das categorias específicas.

No nosso exemplo de consulta acima de todos os produtos da categoria 7 será movido para a categoria com ID 8. Se você não tiver certeza de que as identificações das suas categorias são, de uma maneira de verificar que está no painel de administração do seu Magento. Quando você vai para `Catálogo > Gerenciar Categorias` e você clica em uma categoria, vai mostrar não só as configurações de categoria, mas também o seu nome e ID (no topo, acima das configurações de categoria).

Depois de executar a consulta reindexar os dados Magento. Você pode fazer isso a partir do painel de administração do `Sistema > Gerenciar Índices`.

[Fonte](http://www.hostknox.com/clients/knowledgebase/423/How-to-use-phpMyAdmin-to-move-products-from-one-category-to-another-in-Magento.html)